# access-control-allow-origin not working?

Tags: htaccess

I've seen similar questions asked here but I am still unable to solve this issue. I'm running Typekit and FontAwesome (from CDN) and I get the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://resource.com/example/example. Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Now, the typekit font and fontawesome css stylesheet are loading perfectly fine, so I'm not sure why the error :\

I have already tried to setup CORS through .htaccess but even then I still get the error. Does anyone have a recommendation for this problem?

This is happening in both, my local and production server.

Comment: In Firefox or all browsers? Firefox is REALLY weird about cross-domain font requests in ways that other browsers are not. It's very annoying.

Comment: I'm actually using Chrome. I've tried disabling web security but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Commonly you need to define [CORS](https://www.keycdn.com/support/cors/) on your server if you want to allow ​3rd party URLs to load other assets. Just check the following configuration examples where you set the CORS header to allow everything (*). Just replace the `*` with the desired domain if you want to be restrictive.

**Apache**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

**Nginx**

```
location ~ \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a browser problem. Modern browsers blocks cross domain requests.

Try to use Google Chrome with args.

On Windows: `--disable-web-security`

On Mac: `-disable-web-security`

Comment: Hmmm, even with that I'm still seeing the error. I think I'll just ignore it for now. It seems to be an issue in their servers so maybe I need to get in touch with Typekit about it.
Thanks!